# Loop through array and return multiple rows based on one or more search criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, search

I am looping through ArrayDestination through two columns (customer name and process number).
I am looping through ArraySourceData to find matches (invoice number and amount) for the above search criteria.

If there is a match it gets copied to the array and once both loops finish the results get copied to the worksheet.

So far it works except that the loop is only returning the first match.

If a customer has multiple identical process numbers the loop only returns the first match for all of them.

My b variable looks a bit static and I tried to cheer it up with b = b + 1.

For simplicity I didn't post creating the array part. It works. If needed I can provide it.

```
Sub search_loop_arrray()

For a = 2 To UBound(ArraySourceData)
    varCustomerName = ArraySourceData(a, 3)
    varProcessNumber = ArraySourceData(a, 5)

    For b = 2 To UBound(ArrayDestination)
        If ArrayDestination(b, 3) = varCustomerName And _
          ArrayDestination(b, 8) = varProcessNumber Then

            ArrayDestination(b, 9) = ArraySourceData(a, 11)
            ArrayDestination(b, 10) = ArraySourceData(a, 12)

            Exit For
        End If
    Next b
Next a

'transfer data (invoice number and amount) from ArrayDestination to wsDestination (Column 9 and 10)
For a = 2 To UBound(ArraySourceData)
    For b = 9 To 10
        wsDestination.Cells(a, b).Value = ArrayDestination(a, b)
    Next b
Next a

End Sub
```

---

02/02/2020

I rewrote the code in a nested for loop without the array. This code works. The problem is there are duplicated process numbers in my source data.

In my example I "cut and paste" the already found process numbers in a sheet called coincidences. It is working BUT I was looking to parse everything into an array due to dealing with 100.000+ rows and 20+ columns.

I don't know if my "copy to temporary coincidences sheet" would make sense in the array?

```
Sub find_invoice()

Dim wsSourceData As Worksheet
Dim wsResults As Worksheet
Dim wsCoincidences As Worksheet

Dim varCustomer As String
Dim varProcessNumber As Long
Dim varInvoiceNumber As Long
Dim varSDlastrow As Integer
Dim varRElastrow As Long
Dim varCIlastrow As Long
Dim varCounterResults As Long

Set wsResults = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESULTS")
Set wsSourceData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOURCEDATA")
Set wsCoincidences = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COINCIDENCES")

varSDlastrow = wsSourceData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
varRElastrow = wsResults.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
varCIlastrow = wsCoincidences.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To varRElastrow
    varCustomer = wsResults.Cells(i, 1)
    varProcessNumber = wsResults.Cells(i, 2)

    For j = 2 To varSDlastrow
        If wsSourceData.Cells(j, 1) = varCustomer And wsSourceData.Cells(j, 2) = varProcessNumber Then
            wsResults.Cells(i, 3) = wsSourceData.Cells(j, 3)
            wsResults.Cells(i, 4) = wsSourceData.Cells(j, 4)
            wsCoincidences.Rows(varCIlastrow).EntireRow.Value = wsSourceData.Rows(j).EntireRow.Value
            wsSourceData.Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
            varCIlastrow = varCIlastrow + 1

            Exit For
        End If

    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't hard-code the lower bound of the array, use `LBound`.

Comment: He BigBen, thanks for your quick response. Do you mean: For a = LBound(ArraySourceData) To UBound(ArraySourceData) ? I tried but it doesn´t make a difference. Shouldn´t it iterate through all rows anyway?

Comment: Yes that is exactly right.

Comment: Unfortunately it´s still returning the first match only. Any other idea?

Comment: Looks like the `Exit For` causes it to only find the first match?

Comment: I´ll took it out. Same result. I keeps copying the same line for all search criteria. What are we missing?

Comment: You are missing sensible variable names :). First loop b is the arraydestination row counter and that is the array you should be looping through in the second loop. Maybe use b again (in place of a) and c for 9,10.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, you are right and you pointed me in the right direction. Very helpful!! Thanks a lot.  Please see code below for updated question.

Comment: How many rows/columns in each of the  3 worksheet. Is this macro run often and do you retain the results of each run on this workbook ? When it is runs how long does it take ? Usually a lot of input is a reason not to use an array (unless your PC has gigabytes of memory and you want a faster run time).

Comment: The actual code I am building runs the same way but with multiple if statements / search conditions. At the moment (in development) I run them manually one after another depending on the results of the previous loop. 10.000 rows of search criteria * 100.000 rows of source data * 10 conditions. The source data is retained to be to be used later on. Manually Color coded at the moment. The array version (which partially worked) took approx 20 seconds with one if statement. The worksheet version runs just forever. Don’t have exact time with me right now.

Comment: Looks like you need a database, anyway with regard to the code you posted are what you call "Search Criteria" the rows on the Result sheet (2 columns Name & Number) and one of the 10 "Conditions" is matching those 2 values to records in the source file ? The reason I ask is I have a alternative using a dictionary object which should be much quicker but I'm not sure it will help for the 9 other coditions. Would you like it anyway ?

Comment: Database is the next step( once data gets more consistent) I will post some sample data to give more information as it is difficult to explain without. Thank you again for your time. ☺️

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're logic is right. If you are saying you need to match 2 parameters and several entities can contain those two parameters, then I don't see how you can do anything other than find either the first or last occurrence. Wouldn't you need a third parameter to distinguish the matches?

You'll see in the sample code below, I've assumed that the source data has the list of invoices which are sequential and the destination data has the duplicate customer and process parameters. In this case I've assumed that the invoice matching on the destination sheet should also be sequential, ie 2nd occurrence of duplicate means match the 2nd occurence of an invoice. So here, 'sequence' becomes the third parameter, but yours may be different.

It might also be easier to format your data into a hierarchical structure:

> customer -> process -> invoice

so you can see what's going on a little easier. `Classes` are ideal for this. Your code is hard to follow as that `Exit For` will guarantee a first match only, and the transfer loop iterates on the upperbound of the `ArraySourceData` array and yet processes the `ArrayDestination` (I can't see what you're trying to do there, unless it's an error).

To show you what I mean, create three classes (*Insert~>Class Module*) called *cCustomer*, *cProcess* and *cInvoice*. Add the following code to each:

**cCustomer**

```
Option Explicit

Public Name As String
Public Processes As Collection
Public Sub AddInvoice(processNum As String, invoiceNum As String, invAmount As Double)
    Dim process As cProcess
    Dim invoice As cInvoice

    On Error Resume Next
    Set process = Processes(processNum)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If process Is Nothing Then
        Set process = New cProcess
        With process
            .ProcessNumber = processNum
            Processes.Add process, .ProcessNumber
        End With
    End If

    Set invoice = New cInvoice
    With invoice
        .InvoiceNumber = invoiceNum
        .Amount = invAmount
        process.Invoices.Add invoice
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetProcess(num As String) As cProcess
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetProcess = Processes(num)
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Processes = New Collection
End Sub
```

**cProcess**

```
Option Explicit

Public ProcessNumber As String
Public Invoices As Collection
Public CurrentInvoiceCount As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Invoices = New Collection
End Sub
```

**cInvoice**

```
Option Explicit

Public InvoiceNumber As String
Public Amount As Double
Public ArrayIndex As Long
```

The following routine in your Module will output the data as I described above:

```
Dim customers As Collection
Dim customer As cCustomer
Dim process As cProcess
Dim invoice As cInvoice
Dim srcData As Variant, dstData As Variant
Dim output() As Variant

Dim i As Long

'Populate the source data array.
'Note: just an example here, use whatever array populating code you have.
With Sheet1 'I've put some dummy data in my Sheet1.
    srcData = _
        .Range( _
                .Cells(2, "A"), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
        .Resize(, 12) _
        .Value2
End With

'Populate the destination data array.
'Note: just an example here, use whatever array populating code you have.
With Sheet2 'I've put some dummy data in my Sheet2.
    dstData = _
        .Range( _
                .Cells(2, "A"), _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
        .Resize(, 10) _
        .Value2
End With

'Convert source array to heirarchical collections.
Set customers = New Collection
For i = 1 To UBound(srcData, 1)
    Set customer = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
    Set customer = customers(CStr(srcData(i, 3))): On Error GoTo 0
    If customer Is Nothing Then
        Set customer = New cCustomer
        With customer
            .Name = CStr(srcData(i, 3))
            customers.Add customer, .Name
        End With
    End If
    customer.AddInvoice CStr(srcData(i, 5)), CStr(srcData(i, 11)), CDbl(srcData(i, 12))
Next

'Match destination array.
For i = 1 To UBound(dstData, 1)
    Set customer = Nothing: On Error Resume Next
    Set customer = customers(CStr(dstData(i, 3))): On Error GoTo 0
    If Not customer Is Nothing Then
        Set process = customer.GetProcess(CStr(dstData(i, 8)))
        If Not process Is Nothing Then
            With process
                .CurrentInvoiceCount = .CurrentInvoiceCount + 1
                If .CurrentInvoiceCount > .Invoices.Count Then
                    MsgBox "No further invoices for [cust=" & customer.Name & ";" & process.ProcessNumber & "]"
                Else
                    Set invoice = .Invoices(.CurrentInvoiceCount)
                    invoice.ArrayIndex = i
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next

'Populate the output array.
ReDim output(1 To UBound(dstData, 1), 1 To 2)
For Each customer In customers
    For Each process In customer.Processes
        For Each invoice In process.Invoices
            With invoice
                If .ArrayIndex > 0 Then
                    output(.ArrayIndex, 1) = .InvoiceNumber
                    output(.ArrayIndex, 2) = .Amount
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
Next

'Write array to worksheet
Sheet2.Cells(2, 9).Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
```

Without seeing some sample data, it's difficult to be certain, but I suspect my point is: if only a combination of three of parameters makes something unique, then you'll need to match against those three parameters.

Comment: That´s a very helpful answer and I will keep your code and suggestions in mind for the future because this is where I want to go one day. At the moment it´s beyond my vba knowledge and not possible yet due to the fact that I am dealing with very inconsistent data. I edited my question as I am more clear now what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 100,000 rows on the SOURCEDATA sheet and 10,000 rows of the RESULTS sheet then having 2 loops is 1,000,000,000 iterations. The efficient way is to use a [dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) using a key constructed on your 2 match criteria (col1 and col2) joined by a character of your choice such a "~" (tilde) or "_" (underscore). Scan the SOURCEDATA sheet once to build a "look up" of key to row number. Then scan the RESULTS sheet once, concatenate the 2 fields as before and using the dictionary .exists(key) method to find a match will give you the relevant row number on SOURCEDATA. Here is some code to illustrate. I tested it with 100,000 source rows and 10,000 results rows of random data matching the keys and filling in col C and D on the RESULTS sheet take around 3 seconds. Add a sheet called RUNLOG for the performance figures. It looks a lot of code but much of it is logging.

```
Option Explicit

Sub find_invoice2()

    Const MSG As Boolean = False ' TRUE to show message boxes
    Const RUNLOG As Boolean = False ' TRUE to log matches, no match etc

    Dim wb As Workbook, start As Single, finish As Single
    start = Timer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    ' set up sheets
    Dim wsSourceData As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet, wsLog As Worksheet, wsMatch
    With wb
        Set wsResults = .Sheets("RESULTS")
        Set wsSourceData = .Sheets("SOURCEDATA")
        Set wsMatch = .Sheets("COINCIDENCES")
        Set wsLog = .Sheets("RUNLOG")
    End With

    ' find last row of source and results
    Dim lastRowSource As Long, lastRowResults As Long, lastRowLog As Long, lastRowMatch
    lastRowSource = wsSourceData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowResults = wsResults.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowMatch = wsMatch.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ' set up log sheets
    wsLog.Cells.Clear
    wsLog.Range("A1:E1") = Array("Source Row", "Result Row", "Customer~Process", "Message", "Date Time")
    wsLog.Cells(2, 4) = "Started"
    wsLog.Cells(2, 5) = Time

    lastRowLog = 3

    ' create lookup from Source
    ' key = Name~ProcessID, value = array row
    Dim dict As Object, sKey As String, iRow As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With wsSourceData
    For iRow = 2 To lastRowSource
        sKey = CStr(.Cells(iRow, 1)) & "~" & CStr(.Cells(iRow, 2)) ' customer~process
        If Len(sKey) > 1 Then ' skip blanks lines if any
            If dict.exists(sKey) Then

                dict.Item(sKey) = dict.Item(sKey) & "_" & CStr(iRow)

                If MSG Then MsgBox "Ignoring duplicate key in Source Data " & sKey, vbCritical
                If RUNLOG Then
                With wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 1)
                    .Offset(0, 0) = iRow
                    .Offset(0, 2) = sKey
                    .Offset(0, 3) = "Source : Ignoring duplicate key "
                    .Offset(0, 4) = Time
                End With
                lastRowLog = lastRowLog + 1
                End If
            Else
                dict.Add sKey, iRow
                'Debug.Print "Dict add", sKey, iRow
            End If
        End If
    Next
    End With
    If MSG Then MsgBox dict.Count & " records added to dictionary"

    wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 4) = "Dictionary Built Keys Count = " & dict.Count
    wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 5) = Time
    lastRowLog = lastRowLog + 1 ' blank line to seperate results

    ' scan results sheet
    Dim sDict As String, countMatch As Long, countNoMatch As Long, sMsg As String
    Dim ar As Variant, i As Long
    countMatch = 0: countNoMatch = 0

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wsResults
    For iRow = 2 To lastRowResults
        sKey = CStr(.Cells(iRow, 1)) & "~" & CStr(.Cells(iRow, 2)) ' customer~process
        If Len(sKey) > 1 Then 'skip blanks lines if any
            If dict.exists(sKey) Then

                ' split string to get multiple lines
                sDict = dict(sKey)
                ar = Split(sDict, "_")
                .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = UBound(ar) + 1
                For i = 0 To UBound(ar)
                  .Cells(iRow, 4).Offset(0, i) = ar(i)
                Next

                lastRowMatch = lastRowMatch + 1
                countMatch = countMatch + 1

                If RUNLOG Then
                    With wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 1)
                        .Offset(0, 0) = sDict
                        .Offset(0, 1) = iRow
                        .Offset(0, 2) = sKey
                        .Offset(0, 3) = "Match - Source record deleted"
                        .Offset(0, 4) = Time
                    End With
                    lastRowLog = lastRowLog + 1
                End If
                'Debug.Print iRow,sDict, sKey,
            Else
                ' no match
                If MSG Then MsgBox "Results Row " & iRow & ": NO match for " & sKey, vbExclamation, "NO match"
                countNoMatch = countNoMatch + 1
                If RUNLOG Then
                    With wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 1)
                        .Offset(0, 1) = iRow
                        .Offset(0, 2) = sKey
                        .Offset(0, 3) = "Results : NO match"
                        .Offset(0, 4) = Time
                        .EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    End With
                    .Cells(iRow, 3).Resize(1, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    lastRowLog = lastRowLog + 1
                    'Debug.Print iRow, sDict, sKey,
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 4) = "Program Ended Rows Scanned = " & lastRowResults - 1
    wsLog.Cells(lastRowLog, 5) = Time
    wsLog.Columns.AutoFit
    wsLog.Activate
    wsLog.Columns("A:B").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    wsLog.Range("A1").Select

    ' result
    finish = Timer
    sMsg = "Matched  = " & countMatch & vbCrLf _
         & "NO match = " & countNoMatch & vbCrLf _
         & "Run time (secs) = " & Int(finish - start)
    MsgBox sMsg, vbInformation, "Results"

End Sub
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing. I have always been scared of dictionaries but seeing it with my own example it does not look rocket science anymore. However I have to get into it to fully understand what´s going on. The problem with your code is - my initial problem. It returns the first match and ignores further matches. Imagine a customer with 4 rows of same process numbers which belong to different invoices. The code then should return the n number of matches and  not only the first one. I KNOW it is hard to understand and probably doesn´t make sense if you are not familiar with my project.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time!!! I am absolutely overwhelmed.

Comment: @Chris Which table SOURCE or RESULTS has the duplicate keys or is it both ?

Comment: both of them can have duplicates

Comment: OK, I have edited my code. It works by building a string of the multiple match rows with an underscore ie 123_456_789. The results sheet now shows in Col C the number of matches and in Col D, E, F etc the actual row numbers

Comment: You are a Star! I love your approach and the code is very, very fast. Awesome!! Now I can easily build on top of your code with different search criteria (customer, date, invoice amount, etc.) You are my star. I am new in this forum so if there is anything I can do for you just let me know . Thank you very much again for all your time!